# How to receive my own telegram messages in node.js by telegram client written in node.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, telegram

I want to make a simple telegram client running on ubuntu 20.04 by node.js. i follow the tutorial on this page :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898262/how-to-receive-my-own-telegram-messages-in-node-js-without-bot
```

but unfortunately when i want to run the following command to install "telegram-mtproto" :

```
npm install --save telegram-mtproto@beta
```

i got the following error :

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/MTProxy/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/MTProxy/package.json'
npm WARN worker-loader@0.8.1 requires a peer of webpack@>=0.9 <2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN MTProxy No description
npm WARN MTProxy No repository field.
npm WARN MTProxy No README data
npm WARN MTProxy No license field.

+ telegram-mtproto@2.2.2
updated 1 package and audited 61 packages in 0.986s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 2 moderate severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

and the sample script wont work.
can anybody please help me to solve this problem and run a simple telegram client in node.js.

my target code to run is :

```js
import MTProto from 'telegram-mtproto'

const phone = {
  num : '+90555555555', // basically it is your phone number
  code: '22222' // your 2FA code
}

const api = {
  layer          : 57,
  initConnection : 0x69796de9,
  api_id         : 111111
}

const server = {
  dev: true //We will connect to the test server.
}           //Any empty configurations fields can just not be specified

const client = MTProto({ server, api })

async function connect(){
  const { phone_code_hash } = await client('auth.sendCode', {
    phone_number  : phone.num,
    current_number: false,
    api_id        : 111111, // obtain your api_id from telegram
    api_hash      : 'helloapi-hash' // obtain api_hash from telegram
  })
  const { user } = await client('auth.signIn', {
    phone_number   : phone.num,
    phone_code_hash: phone_code_hash,
    phone_code     : phone.code
  })
      console.log('signed as ', user);
    }

    connect();
```

best regards : mehdi

Comment: have you tried to do `npm init` in your project folder? seems like your package.json file is missing...

Comment: can you please guide me step by step ?